# Where created ApplicationContext in web project?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

There is code from some example project (without using servlet):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
ExampleBean exampleBean = (ExampleBean) ctx.getBean("exampleBean");
System.out.println(exampleBean.sayHello());
```

I see, that we directly create ApplicationContext and get beans from it.
But in examples with servlets I don't found where ApplicationContext  is created.

Can anybody says me this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application (not required) `ApplicationcContext` is created by a `ContextLoaderListener`.

The Servlet (required) `ApplicationContext` is created by the `DispatcherServlet` using the `ContextLoaderListener`'s `ApplicationContext` as a parent if it exists.

Comment: And, if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @qwerre It doesn't use it.